# Get cell value if SUM exceeds a limit using R

Tags: r

I have a huge data frame with details of each employee's working hours per day. For e.g:

```
STAFF_ID  DATE  MONTH  HOURS_WORKED
345  4-May-15   May     5
678  4-May-15   May     2
965  4-May-15   May     4
248  4-May-15   May     6
345  5-May-15   May     7 
678  6-May-15   May     3
678  7-May-15   May     3
965  8-May-15   May     5
345  7-Jun-15   June    1
678  8-Jun-15   June    2
965  8-Jun-15   June    4
248  8-Jun-15   June    6
345  8-Jun-15   June    3
678  9-Jun-15   June    2
678  10-Jun-15  June    3
965  11-Jun-15  June    4
965  12-Jun-15  June    3
```

What I want to find out is if any employee works more than 7 hours per month, and if there is,:

- When is the latest day which the employee works on which results in the total hour to be greater than 7, and
- for that latest day, how much did it exceed the maximum by?

Expected results:

```
STAFF_ID  DATE  MONTH  HOURS_WORKED  LATEST_DATE  HOURS_EXCEED
    345  4-May-15   May     5    5-May-15    5
    678  4-May-15   May     2    7-May-15    1
    965  4-May-15   May     4    8-May-15    2
    248  4-May-15   May     6    NA    NA
    345  5-May-15   May     7    5-May-15    5 
    678  6-May-15   May     3    7-May-15    1
    678  7-May-15   May     3    7-May-15    1
    965  8-May-15   May     5    8-May-15    2
    345  7-Jun-15   June    1    NA    NA
    678  8-Jun-15   June    2    NA    NA
    965  8-Jun-15   June    4    11-Jun-15   1
    248  8-Jun-15   June    6    NA    NA
    345  8-Jun-15   June    3    NA    NA
    678  9-Jun-15   June    2    NA    NA
    678  10-Jun-15  June    3    NA    NA
    965  11-Jun-15  June    4    11-Jun-15   1
    965  12-Jun-15  June    3    11-Jun-15   1
```

I have also asked the same question, but in that question, I asked for Excel solutions. However, as mentioned, the data file is really huge, hence, I would prefer if I could solve this using R.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

**Updated**

Using `data.table` with custom function, assuming `DATE` is of class `date`.

```
library(data.table)

# Calculate cumulative sum of hours worked per month per group
setDT(df)[,total_hours := cumsum(HOURS_WORKED),by = c("STAFF_ID", "MONTH")] 

# Define custom function which selects first match that is total_hours > 7
over.seven <- function(x,z) {
  y <- x[(z>7)][1]
  return(y)
}

# Add desired columns
df[,`:=`(LATEST_DATE = over.seven(DATE,total_hours),
     HOURS_EXCEED = over.seven(total_hours - 7,total_hours)),
     by = c("STAFF_ID", "MONTH")]

> df
#    STAFF_ID       DATE MONTH HOURS_WORKED total_hours LATEST_DATE HOURS_EXCEED
# 1:      345 2015-05-04   May            5           5  2015-05-05            5
# 2:      678 2015-05-04   May            2           2  2015-05-07            1
# 3:      965 2015-05-04   May            4           4  2015-05-08            2
# 4:      248 2015-05-04   May            6           6        <NA>           NA
# 5:      345 2015-05-05   May            7          12  2015-05-05            5
# 6:      678 2015-05-06   May            3           5  2015-05-07            1
# 7:      678 2015-05-07   May            3           8  2015-05-07            1
# 8:      965 2015-05-08   May            5           9  2015-05-08            2
# 9:      345 2015-06-07  June            1           1        <NA>           NA
#10:      678 2015-06-08  June            2           2        <NA>           NA
#11:      965 2015-06-08  June            4           4  2015-06-11            1
#12:      248 2015-06-08  June            6           6        <NA>           NA
#13:      345 2015-06-08  June            3           4        <NA>           NA
#14:      678 2015-06-09  June            2           4        <NA>           NA
#15:      678 2015-06-10  June            3           7        <NA>           NA
#16:      965 2015-06-11  June            4           8  2015-06-11            1
#17:      965 2015-06-12  June            3          11  2015-06-11            1
```

Comment: You forgot to mention the `setDT(df)[, DATE := as.IDate(DATE, "%d-%b-%y")]` step

Comment: Thank you for the solution! However, I am facing another issue, and I guess that's because my example is not comprehensive enough.

Issue: The solution proposed the last date for the staff in the particular in instances where sum of hours worked > 85. However, if the staff hits the maximum _before_ the last date, values would not reflect accurately.

I have updated my dataset above.

Comment: @pinchofsalt answer updated. I would recommend updating the question though as it took me a while to figure out what you meant.